# Re-using CSS classes while changing content

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I would like to reuse the following CSS for multiple `content` labels (top-right corner). For example, `Foo`, `Bar`,  `Baz`, etc.

Is it possible to re-use as much of the existing style without duplicating the full code? In the example below `foo` and `bar` are identical with the exception of `content` string in `.foo:after` and `.bar:after`.

```css
.foo {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 1em 1em 0.5em 1em;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
}

.foo:after {
    content: "Foo";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    padding: 3px 7px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #9da0a4;
    border-radius: 0px 4px 0px 4px;
    border-width: 0px 0px 1px 1px;
}

.bar {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 1em 1em 0.5em 1em;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
}

.bar:after {
    content: "Bar";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    padding: 3px 7px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #9da0a4;
    border-radius: 0px 4px 0px 4px;
    border-width: 0px 0px 1px 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  Hello
</div>

<p/>

<div class="bar">
  Mama!
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way! use `attr(data-content)` to reduce CSS classes

```css
.x {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 1em 1em 0.5em 1em;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
}

.x:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  padding: 3px 7px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #9da0a4;
  border-radius: 0px 4px 0px 4px;
  border-width: 0px 0px 1px 1px;
}

.x:after {
  content: attr(data-content);
}
```

```html
<div class="x" data-content="foo">
  Hello
</div>
<p/>

<div class="x" data-content="bar">
  World!
</div>
<p/>

<div class="x" data-content="seomthing else">
  Something!
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use a common class for the common settings and seperate classes for the different settings:

```css
.x {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 1em 1em 0.5em 1em;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
}

.x:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  padding: 3px 7px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #9da0a4;
  border-radius: 0px 4px 0px 4px;
  border-width: 0px 0px 1px 1px;
}

.foo:after {
  content: "Foo";
}

.bar:after {
  content: "Bar";
}
```

```html
<div class="x foo">
  Hello
</div>

<p/>

<div class="x bar">
  Mama!
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```css
    .foo, .bar {
            position: relative;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            padding: 1em 1em 0.5em 1em;
            border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    }
    .foo:after, .bar:after {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            right: 0px;
            padding: 3px 7px;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-weight: bold;
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            color: #9da0a4;
            border-radius: 0px 4px 0px 4px;
            border-width: 0px 0px 1px 1px;
    }
    .foo:after {
            content: "Foo";
    }

    .bar:after {
            content: "Bar";
    }
```

```html
    <div class="foo">
      Hello
    </div>

    <p/>

    <div class="bar">
      Mama!
    </div>
```